# Margin on H1 element

Tags: html, css

So I have a margin on my H1 element that I want to remove.

I have tried adding

```
h1 {
margin 0;
}
```

But cannot seem to remove this.
I have tried all sorts of things to resolve this but just end up messing up the media Queries when I put them in. I have remove these for now in order to try and fix the issue.

Website is [blupace](https://dev.blupace.com)

The issue is between the Title BLUPACE and PHOTOGRAPHY.

Thanks everyone...

Comment: it's working in your site.. what the issue?

Comment: I can't seem to find the margin of the `h1` element when I checked in the dev tools

Comment: `margin 0;` => `margin: 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the issue of the `margin` the gap is due to `line-height` you have used `vw` for `font-size` so you better go with:

```
#photo h1 {
    font-family: 'CODE-Light';
    font-size: 7.1vw;
    line-height: 4vw;
}
```

**About `line-height`:** *The line-height CSS property sets the amount of space used for lines, such as in text. On block-level elements, it specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element. On non-replaced inline elements, it specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height.*

This will work fine for you, if there is anything else please do ask.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION BUT**
I was just looking at your website and I'd recommend you to add

```
cursor: pointer;
```

to your navigation links.

```
<a id="btn-fashion" class="btn-lb" onclick="FWDRL.show('rlobj_fashion', 
0);">FASHION</a>
```

It's just so your users know that this is a clickable link.

Another thing I'd recommend is putting your X icon (which appears when you open your navigation) on the same place where you've put your hamburger icon.

Comment: Thanks Tim, those are both great suggestions, and advice I will certainly take :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `margin` on h1. Use `line-height` to reduce the distance:

```
#blupace h1 {
    font-family: "Code-Bold";
    font-size: 12vw;
    line-height: 92px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.right` have `padding-top: 30px;`,So

for fix change like:

```
.right {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```